# Material Design Icons not rendering properly when src: local() included in @font-face definition

Tags: css, webfonts

I recently installed a new arch linux system, using deepin and gnome shell as desktop environment. 
Updated entire system on September 17 2019
Using chromium Version 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit) I came upon the following issue:

I have a web app that uses material-design-icons pulled from npm and built with webpack. In the end, this is the final CSS that is rendered (with regards to @font-face):

```
@font-face {
        font-family: Material Icons;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url(fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot);
        src: local("Material Icons"), local("MaterialIcons-Regular"), url(fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format("woff2"), url(fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format("woff"), url(fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format("truetype")
    }
```

The result is that the browser does not render the Icons and instead renders another font in its place. 
If I remove the line src: local("Material Design Icons") or place it above the other URLs, everything works.
Also, if I install Material Design Icons locally on the machine (i.e. ttf-material-icons-git from aur), it also works and I can see that chromium is rendering from local version.
But, to my understanding, even if the src:local is the last entry, if the font is not installed locally, shouldn't the browser just download from the other URLs?
I have tried refreshing local font cache and even uninstalled

Also, note that the page works perfectly on the system when accessed with firefox (Mozilla Firefox 69.0)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, subsequent valid CSS property re-declaration in same rule set overrides preceding instances of same property.

```
* {
 color: red;
 color: blue; /* "wins" */
 color: blargh;
}
```

In your case the last valid `src` property declaration is `src: local("Material Design Icons");`, but presumably you (as well as most other folks) do not have locally installed font with this identifier [1].  Since previous `src` declarations were trashed already, there is no fallback to remote version in effect.

---

`@font-face` is a bit special case where -- for historic reasons -- is common to have two `src` declarations: first without `format()` for ancient browser that do not understand the latter verbose, what is invalid and thus ignored in their perspective.

You probably want to put the `local` part in the beginning of that second rule, so that it will be first try in the fallback chain: `src: local(..), url(..eot) format("embedded-opentype") /*and so on*/;`.

---

[1] looking at the [guide](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web) the identifier should be either "Material Icons" or "MaterialIcons-Regular".

Comment: After reading your answer, I realized I had copied the @font-face erroneously. I have edited the question and copied the correct code. Your answer does work, however, but the problem is that the project that I am working on is using material icons from NPM, and so I don't have control over how it generates the css. Also, it's strange that it works on same version of chromium on other arch linux instalations and on firefox on this version machine that also don't have the localfont installed.

Comment: If your app is built properly and those `url(fonts/..)` paths points to proper files, it indeed should work even without local font installed.

Comment: I finally found the issue. It turns out the issue was not in the web-app at all, but rather a problem with FontConfg and chromium. I posted an answer to my original question outlining what I found.

Answer (score 0):

So after racking my brain for well over a week with this issue, I finally found the cause and fixed it. I thought I'd post the root problem and solution I encountered here, as it was a very peculiar case.

So to be clear on the problem, it only happens on CHROMIUM in CERTAIN installations running on Linux. It did not happen on Firefox in any of my installations. I was able to reproduce the problem by installing a fresh copy of Arch Linux and the Deepin desktop environment. I did this various times and found that if I chose a different Desktop (i.e. Gnome, Plasma, etc.) the problem did not occur. If however, I installed Gnome or Plasma AFTER having installed Deepin, the problem would persist, even if I removed all Deepin packages.

After much tinkering, I finally found that the problem could be traced to a specific FontConfig configuration. In the installations where the problem occurred, there was a file located at etc/fonts/local.conf with various "match" and "edit" elements. I managed to isolate the exact element that caused the problem. here  is a striped down version of the file containing only the element in question. If I place this file in any of my installations, chromium presents the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  <fontconfig>
      <match>
          <edit mode="prepend" name="family"><string>Noto Sans</string></edit>
      </match>
  </fontconfig>
```

Anyway, either removing this file or simply removing the "prepend" element from the file solved the problem for me, but I still don't know if this is a "buggy" configuration or a bug in chromium or a bug in FontConfig.